# Ignore certain packages from ppa

Tags: ppa

I've been using Elementary Desktop for a while, but after the last update, Docky have broken. I've tried using the Docky stable ppa, but it is overridden by the Elementary ppa, as they provide a newer version of Docky.

I would like to keep receiving updates to the Elementary theme, but I would also like to use the older version of Docky. Is there any way I can do this, or do I simply have to file a bug and wait?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pinning the the older version of docky or setting a higher priority for the the single deb in an empty repo would solve the problem